# Animation nodes Group instances

Tags: animation-nodes, instances

[image]
I want to know if there is anyway I can make random instances of a group or list of object in to a mesh.
In the example I want to instance the 4 objects in to the 8 vertex of the big cube. 
I tried also whit the instancer node but doesn't work

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *Object Instancer Node* to create a number of empty objects, fill a random list of the required source objects, copy the mesh data from the random object list to the empty objects, then position them as you want.

[image: Node Tree]